# Memory efficient storage of many large scipy sparse matrices

Tags: python, memory, dictionary, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to store around 50.000 scipy sparse csr matrices where each matrix is a vector of length 3.7Million:

```
x = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((3.7Mill,1))
```

I currently store them into a simple dictionary, because I also need to know the corresponding key for each vector (in this case the key is just a simple integer).

The problem now is the huge amount of memory needed. Are there some more efficient ways?

Comment: You could store them in a single matrix instead of 50k of them. You could also use a smaller `dtype`. What do you need these matrices for?

Comment: Thanks, so simple and I think I have solved my problems now. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) data structures.

For example:

```
def lazy(func):
    def lazyfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        temp = lambda x : func(*args, **kwargs)
        temp.__name__ = "lazy-" + func.__name__
        return temp
    return lazyfunc

"""
Add some simple functions
"""
def add(x, y):
    print "Not lazy"
    return x + y

@lazy
def add_lazy(x, y):
    print "lazy!"
    return x + y
```

Usage:

```
>>> add(1, 2)
Not lazy
3
$ add_lazy(1, 2)
<function lazy-add_lazy at 0x021E9470>
>>> myval = add_lazy(1, 2)
>>> myval()
lazy!
3
```

Look at:

- http://finderweb.com/blog/lazy_dict/
- http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~kmk592/rants/lazy-python/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, sounds promising. If I udnerstand this right this method postpones the execution until it is required. But in my case I also fill the sparse matrices beforehand and then pass it to the dictionary. So I create this 50k sparse vectors, fill them and then add them to the dictionary. Is this also possible with this lazy method?

Comment: Sure, why not? Apparently no problems should occur.